# Autofac - Force Delegate Factories to pass a new instance even if type is registred as InstancePerRequest

Tags: autofac, factory, unit-of-work

i am using Autofac Delegate Factory Feature:
http://autofaccn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced/delegate-factories.html

The problem is that when i register a type as in my Web Application example:

```
builder.RegisterType<UnitOfWork>().As<IUnitOfWork>().InstancePerRequest();
```

And i want that normally it should be injected once per HTTP Request.

Sometime i need to obtain a new separate instance (ex. for achieve a different transaction)

When i register the delegate:

```
public delegate IUnitOfWork UnitOfWorkFactory();
```

That is injected (because the delegate factory feature) automatically when i use it i would like to obtain a new complete instance.

Is there maybe another way to obtain it?

Thank you

Comment: I suspect that this is not a technical issue but a design one. You either control instance lifetime fully by yourself using something like `Func<Owned<IService>>` factory or do not touch it at all just requesting instances from container in whatever scope they live leaving full control of their lifetime to container. Mixing those concerns in one scope of code suggests that you're going in wrong direction. So, why do you need to do this?

Comment: Yes, I investigated more and i totally agree with you that is a design behavior. Even using `Func<Owned<IService>>` nothing was changing. I had to change the registration type in InstancePerLifetimeScope() for make it work correctly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to use a combination of OwnedInstances and InstancePerLifetimeScope().

Changinng the regsitration from IntancePerRequest() to InstancePerLifetimeScope() i enabled the possibility to obtain new instances from the factory when inside another scope (and not only the 'global scope' that is created for every HTTP incoming request).

Then encaspulating the factory type inside the Owned generic class i automatically declare that i want the a new scope will be created.

I did it with this kind of declaration:

```
Func<Owned<IService>>
```